# Using Dependency Injection in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, dependency-injection, di

I would love to **use Magento 2's DI in some of my Magento 1 modules.**

I'm not entirely sure how can I approach that and more importantly, **if Magento 1 will allow me to do so ?**

Most of the M1 classes extend `Varien_Object`. Thus, **would injecting the classes the exact same way as M2 be enough to start using DI on M1 ?** Something like this:

```
class Vendor_Module_Model_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    protected $_productCollection;

    public function __construct(
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $productCollection
    ) {
         $this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
         parent::__construct();
    }

    public myFunction($productId)
    {
        return $this->_productCollection->addIdFilter($productId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The biggest question here would be do you need the `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` class and an parent?

How I treat DI in Magento 1.

1. If I need the class to be a "Magento" class as in `Mage::getModel('my/class')` then I will not do di as it will not work with `__construct` so well.
2. If I do not need the class to be a "Magento" class then I will instantiate it with `new Class()` and I can pass in the DI.

**Think about your classes if they really need to be Magento classes and pick the option that fits best for you.**